# BLE Mate 2 bluetooth module to Arduino Uno without FTDI SmartBasic

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, pins, ftdi

So I'm trying to hook up this [BLE breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13019) to an Arduino Uno. SparkFun has a [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bc118-ble-mate-2-hookup-guide?_ga=1.207897426.1342547721.1435176975) which seems to be great for someone who has an FTDI SmartBasic that is mentioned in the article. I don't have the SmartBasic board, and would like to see if this is possible without it.

I have hooked up the board to my Uno with the following pinouts:

```
GRN -> Reset 
RXI -> RX (tried with TX as well) 
TXI -> TX (tried with RX as well) 
VIN -> Tried 5V and 3.3V 
CTS -> GND 
BLK -> (No Connection)
```

I use their [example code](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_BLE_Mate2_Arduino_Library) they have provided, uploaded without the RX and TX pins hooked up because, from what I notice, you cannot upload a program through the USB serial when these ports are in use. So after I upload the program through USB, I power the board with a battery and connect the RX and TX pins to the BLE board.

Has anyone either successfully hooked these up without the use of a SmartBasic? I'm a programmer by trade so I do my best to understand this side of the spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out what I was doing wrong, and want to smack myself for it -.-

The answer was to simply hook up the BLK connection (which I guess is also ground) to a GND pin on the Arduino Uno.

Hope this ends up helping someone out.